# Как в Doctrine 2 в указанном методе как @ORM\PreUpdate правильно сделать flush ?

Tags: doctrine2, doctrine, symfony2

```
class ClassA {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ID")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="Name", nullable=true, length=30)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="Limit", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $limit;

    protected $container

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
       $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
     protected function onLimitChanged(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs){
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof ClassA) {
            if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('limit')) {

            if(!$tmp = $em->getRepository('ACMECommonBundle:ClassB')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'limit_changed'))) {
                $tmp = new \ACME\CommonBundle\Entity\ClassB();
                $tmp->setName('limit_changed');
            }
            $tmp->setValue($this->id);

            $em->persist($tmp);
            $em->flush();

            }
        }

     ***

}

class ClassB {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=30)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
     protected $name
     protected $value;

     ***

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поковырявшись в документации, выяснил, что невозможно сделать persist в [PreUpdate](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate).

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя толкать контейнер или еще какие либо сервисы в сущность. Обрабатывайте сущности "снаружи" толкая их в сервисы.